# ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME on react native webview

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, webview

I'm developing an app with react-native-webview.

And when I click a link with

```
<a href="sms:888888&body=Test Message">Click here</a>
```

I'm receiving error err_unknown_url_scheme.

Thanks

Comment: is this a valid tag btw ? </a> </a>

Comment: Editted the source.

Answer (score 5):

I was getting error regarding "mailto: and tel: links do not work in webview" and for my situation the fix was to adding this property in webview:

```
 <WebView
 // other props here
  originWhitelist={['http://*', 'https://*', 'intent://*']} 
 />
```

Answer (score 2):

Able to solve the problem by editting the webview parameters.

```
<WebView
    {...this.props}
    bounces={false}
    originWhitelist={["https://*", "http://*", "file://*", "sms://*"]}
    allowFileAccess={true}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    geolocationEnabled={true}
    saveFormDataDisabled={true}
    allowFileAccessFromFileURLS={true}
    allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
  />
```

Comment: which webview param actually fixed this?

Comment: originwhitelist

Comment: I had `originWhitelist={['*']}` but apparently that doesn't cover tel: and sms:. Explicitly adding them like the above code fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with `mailto` links within WebViews. I found that this is an open [issue](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/1084) on react-native-webview. Modifying the `originWhitelist` from `{[*]}` to the explicit list as suggested in the answer didn't help me. But I could solve the problem by applying this [fix](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/1084#issuecomment-573434774).
It provides a custom implementation for the `onShouldStartLoadWithRequest` property. And I used

```
function onShouldStartLoadWithRequest(request){
  if (!request || !request.url) {
    return true;
  }

  // list of schemas we will allow the webview
  // to open natively
  if(request.url.startsWith("tel:") ||
    request.url.startsWith("mailto:") ||
    request.url.startsWith("maps:") ||
    request.url.startsWith("geo:") ||
    request.url.startsWith("sms:")
    ){
    Linking.openURL(request.url).catch(er => {
      console.log('Failed to open Link:', er.message);
    });
    return false;
  }

  // let everything else to the webview
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For unknown reasons, even with overriding `onShouldStartLoadWithRequest` method, webview crashed for me.

Version `11.0.0` of `react-native-webview`, features a new option `setSupportMultipleWindows`, which when set to true opens links that open in new tabs/windows (such as `<a target="_blank">`) will now prompt to open in the system browser, rather than re-using the current WebView.

```
<WebView
    // links that open in new tabs/windows will now prompt to open in the system browser
    setSupportMultipleWindows={true}
    // other props here
/>
```

Link that triggers tel

```
<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow noreferrer noopener" href="tel:+91xxxxxxxxx">Call now</a>
```

See https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/1084#issuecomment-735048835